# PHP while function not working

Tags: php, while-loop

I got this simple code:

```
$x = 1999;
while($x != 1949)
{
    echo '<option value="' $x '">' $x '</option>';
    $x = $x - 1;
}
```

But the page isn't loading any more with this code, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate your variables: (notice the dots in your echo)

```
$x = 1999;
while($x != 1949)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$x.'">'.$x.'</option>';
    $x = $x - 1;
}
```

Comment: Damn I forgot the dots :(( thx..

Comment: Please mark this question to be deleted

Comment: You can delete it yourself @donbingo

Comment: I can only flag it for moderation because it contains answers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$x = 1999;
while($x != 1949)
{
    echo '<option value="'. $x .'">'. $x .'</option>';
    $x = $x - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$x = 1999;
while($x != 1949)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$x .'">'. $x. '</option>';
    $x--;
}
```